# Using Arrays To Calculate The Correlation Ratio

Tags: arrays, pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm trying to calculate the correlation ratio between two assets using arrays. However, the code that I've written produces a correlation ratio which only takes on the values of `-1` and `1`. I was wondering if someone could point out the error I've made in the code I've written ?

```
//Obtain user inputs

lookback=input.int(20,"Lookback Period",minval=0,maxval=30,step=1)
source=input.source(close,"Source")
referencemarket=input.symbol("FTX:BTCPERP","Reference Market")     
asset=input.symbol("FTX:ETHPERP","Asset")

//Calculate percentage change data for the reference market

referenceprice=request.security(referencemarket,timeframe.period,source)
referencechange= ((referenceprice[1]-referenceprice[2])/referenceprice[2])*100

//Calculate percentage change data for the asset

assetprice=request.security(asset,timeframe.period,source)
assetchange=((assetprice[1]-assetprice[2])/assetprice[2])*100

//Declare arrays

float[] referencearray=array.new_float(20,0)
float[] assetarray=array.new_float(20,0)

//Remove the last value from the array and adopt the FIFO sorting method

array.shift(referencearray)
array.shift(assetarray)

//Add current values to the respective arrays

array.push(referencearray,referencechange)
array.push(assetarray,assetchange)

//Calculate the covariance 

covariance=array.covariance(referencearray,assetarray)
referencestdev=array.stdev(referencearray)
assetstdev=array.stdev(assetarray)

//Calculate the correlation coefficient

correlation=covariance/(referencestdev*assetstdev)


//Calculate ratio of price of asset to price of reference security

ratio=referenceprice/assetprice

//Plot metrics

//plot(referenceprice)
//plot(assetprice)

plot(correlation)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your arrays with the var keyword, otherwise your arrays will be reinitialized to zeros on each new bar rather than contain the correct values.

```
var float[] referencearray=array.new_float(20,0)
var float[] assetarray=array.new_float(20,0)
```

It is probably better to manage the arrays like this. Then, during the initial historical bars the calculation will be performed with available data until `lookback` number of bars is reached, and from that point on will maintain that number of values in the arrays.

```
var float[] referencearray=array.new_float()
var float[] assetarray=array.new_float()

array.push(referencearray,referencechange)
array.push(assetarray,assetchange)

if array.size(referencearray) > lookback
    array.shift(referencearray)
    array.shift(assetarray)
```